# How to group items from a larger set of items in Swift and excluding certain items? (Example FoodTracker App)

Tags: ios, swift

I completed the example FoodTracker App that is on the Apple Developer site and I would like to modify the FoodTracker slightly. So as of now, the app allows me to add a food item and rate it on a scale of 0-5. This food item and rating is then saved. However, I would like to modify the app by excluding any items rated 2 stars or less from the list of saved items. I am also trying to find a way to search for certain keywords in the user input such as "dairy" or "beef" and exclude these as well. The whole objective of the app is to allow users with stomach issues such as IBS to log foods and rate them on a scale of 0-5 with 0-2 stars providing the least comfort to the stomach. The app will then save these foods with 3-5 stars and exclude those with 0-2 stars. The app will then search for certain keywords in the excluded list such as "milk" "beef" and after a certain period of time, the user will then receive a response such as "John Doe you have excluded oranges, tomatoes, and soda from your diet and therefore it can be concluded that you have a sensitivity to citrus foods." I am not sure how complicated this is and how to develop the algorithm for this, but I will post the code below from the View Controller file. Once again this is the example FoodTracker app from the Swift App Developer site that I am attempting to modify. I am not sure if this was specific enough, so please let me know what I can do to clarify and any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you very much.

****CODE****

import UIKit

class MealViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    // MARK: Properties

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ratingControl: RatingControl!
@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!

/*
This value is either passed by `MealTableViewController` in 
`prepareForSegue(_:sender:)` or constructed as part of adding a new meal
*/
var meal: Meal?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Handle the text field’s user input through delegate callbacks.
    nameTextField.delegate = self

    // set up views if editing an existing meal
    if let existingMeal = meal {
        navigationItem.title = existingMeal.name
        nameTextField.text = existingMeal.name
        photoImageView.image = existingMeal.photo
        ratingControl.rating = existingMeal.rating
    }

    // enable save button only if text field has valid name
    checkValidMealName()
}

// MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    // Disable save button while editing
    saveButton.enabled = true
}

func checkValidMealName() {
    // disable the save button if text field is empty
    let text = nameTextField.text ?? ""
    saveButton.enabled = !text.isEmpty
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Hide the keyboard.
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    checkValidMealName()
    navigationItem.title = textField.text
}

// MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    // Dismiss the picker if the user canceled.
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    // The info dictionary contains multiple representations of the image, and this uses the original.
    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
    photoImageView.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker.
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: Navigation
@IBAction func cancel(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // depending on style of presentation (modal or push), this view
    // controller needs to be dismissed in 2 different ways
    let isPresentingInAddMealMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController

    if isPresentingInAddMealMode {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

}
// configure a view controller before it's passed
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if saveButton === sender {
        let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
        let photo = photoImageView.image
        let rating = ratingControl.rating

        // set meal to be passed to MealTableViewController after unwind segue
        meal = Meal(name: name, photo: photo, rating: rating)
    }
}

// MARK: Actions
@IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Hide the keyboard.
    nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

import UIKit

class MealViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    // MARK: Properties

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ratingControl: RatingControl!
@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!

/*
This value is either passed by `MealTableViewController` in 
`prepareForSegue(_:sender:)` or constructed as part of adding a new meal
*/
var meal: Meal?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Handle the text field’s user input through delegate callbacks.
    nameTextField.delegate = self

    // set up views if editing an existing meal
    if let existingMeal = meal {
        navigationItem.title = existingMeal.name
        nameTextField.text = existingMeal.name
        photoImageView.image = existingMeal.photo
        ratingControl.rating = existingMeal.rating
    }

    // enable save button only if text field has valid name
    checkValidMealName()
}

// MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    // Disable save button while editing
    saveButton.enabled = true
}

func checkValidMealName() {
    // disable the save button if text field is empty
    let text = nameTextField.text ?? ""
    saveButton.enabled = !text.isEmpty
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Hide the keyboard.
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    checkValidMealName()
    navigationItem.title = textField.text
}

// MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    // Dismiss the picker if the user canceled.
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    // The info dictionary contains multiple representations of the image, and this uses the original.
    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
    photoImageView.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker.
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: Navigation
@IBAction func cancel(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // depending on style of presentation (modal or push), this view
    // controller needs to be dismissed in 2 different ways
    let isPresentingInAddMealMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController

    if isPresentingInAddMealMode {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

}
// configure a view controller before it's passed
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if saveButton === sender {
        let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
        let photo = photoImageView.image
        let rating = ratingControl.rating

        // set meal to be passed to MealTableViewController after unwind segue
        meal = Meal(name: name, photo: photo, rating: rating)
    }
}

// MARK: Actions
@IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Hide the keyboard.
    nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: You don't need to provide all your code but the relevant parts.

Comment: Ah okay, my apologies! Also When I mean "exclude certain items" I would like these excluded items to go into a list just as the non-excluded items did. And the program should search for keywords in the excluded list that could be indicative of a sensitivity to dairy products or citrus foods for example.

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter function to do that:

```
self.meal?.filter({ $0.rating > 2})
```

And also for filtering by keywords:

```
self.meal?.filter({ $0.name.rangeOfString("keyword") != nil })
```

Comment: Okay thank you Vladimir! So where would I place these filter functions in the code? Would I include it in the View Controller file?

Comment: @vnus It depends where you want to show them. Also consider that you have to assign it to some variable, for example let filteredMeal = self.meal?.filter... etc. You should do that before showing them filtered or after you insert a new item you should do it again to update the results.

Comment: Okay I have placed the filter function in the rating control file, but it says I need to declare it. I have done the filteredMeal = self.meal.... but I believe it needs a for loop or if statement right? If so, could you please guide me through that as well?

Comment: No it doesn't. Please show me the line you wrote and tell me where did you call it.

Comment: filterMeal = self.meal?.filter({ $0.rating > 2})
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        // Set the button's width and height to a square the size of the frame's height.
        let buttonSize = Int(frame.size.height)

Comment: thats what it looks like. i just added it into the middle of the rating control file. i am not sure where to place it or how to structure it

Comment: I don't see it declared. Is it var or let?

Comment: it would be var filteredMeal = self.Meal... right? is there type that we would have to declare as well?

Comment: also my bad, I have phrased the objective incorrectly. I would like to EXCLUDE anything above 3 stars and include those irritating food times from 0-2 stars.

Comment: @vnus It can be "let" if you are not changing its value later. Well then you have to invert the condition, I think you can do that, right?

Comment: yeah i can invert the condition, that's no problem! and okay, the value will not be changed. so just insert let filteredMeal = self.Meal.. anywhere in the rating control file and it should work?

Comment: Well not anywhere. Think hard, what do you need to be able to filter? First you need that there are meals already. The best thing you could do is put it right before you show them. Are you aware of were is the meals being displaying in code?

Comment: The meals are displayed in the MealViewController File. And I would place this filter right after the "save meal" command?

Comment: Are you using a table view to display the meals?

Comment: Yes i am using table view

Comment: It's hard to say, if you change the value in a different controller you have to be aware about how to pass that value back to the table view controller where unwinding. I suggest you get familiar with those concepts in the tutorial you are following in order to get a better understanding of what you are doing. Give it a try and if you have more doubts just let me know.

Comment: Vladimir, I have placed the filter in the meal view controller (let mealFilter = self.meal?.filter({ $0.rating > 2})) and it gives me this error: Value of type 'NSObject -> () -> MealViewController has no member 'meal'

Comment: How is the name of the variable you use to save the meals?

Comment: That error means there is no meal member, are you sure that's the name you put in that controller?

Comment: which controller would i find this in? meal view controller? rating controller? or table controller? because i have multiple variables such as Meals or Meal

Comment: lass MealTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    // MARK: Properties
    
    var meals = [Meal]()
    let mealFilter = self.meals?.filter({ $0.rating > 2})                                                     this is what the start of the Meal View Controller looks like. i have used the member "meals" and i am still receiving the error.

Comment: Please read the error, it says `MealViewController has no member 'meal'`, there is where you have to look, the message is quite clear.

Comment: That was the old error. it now says MealViewController has no member 'meals' since i switched the member to 'meals' instead of 'meal'

Comment: Yes, I believe you are not reading even what you are writing, it says `MealViewController` but you are looking at `MealTableViewController`.

Comment: I am sorry let me clarify. So I have pasted this code in the MealViewController and I get the error MealViewController has no member 'meal'. When I paste the code in the MealTableViewController I get the error MealTableViewController has no member 'meal'

Comment: I am new to Swift so I am sorry for all this confusion. The tutorial gave me some basic help, but this is confusing. Please explain the error

Comment: The error is self explanatory, there is no member named meals in the class MealViewController. Are you familiar with classes and class members?

Comment: Not very much, i am not familiar with it that well

Comment: I really suggest that you study the basics of object oriented programming (general theory, not for any language) before going any further with Swift, otherwise it will become harder and harder to understand, and it's very difficult to do something if you don't understand its basics. You have to learn to walk to be able to run.